# Shopify: How can I show the current variant value only in liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm creating a product feed using XML + Liquid and I'm trying to send color and size info in the format shown below:

Ex. `<color>`Blue`</color>`
    `<size>`M`</size>`

The liquid code below successfully retrieves and outputs the option name but it displays all of its values instead of the current variant one.

Here is my current code for review:

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}

    {% for product_option in product.options_with_values %}
    <{{ product_option.name }}>{% for value in product_option.values %}{{ value }}{% endfor %}</{{ product_option.name }}>
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Here is an example of the output I am getting

[Screenshot of the feed as it outputs the values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9gka.png)

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how achieved it:

`{% if product.options.size == 1 %} <{{ product.options.first }}>{{ variant.option1 }}</{{ product.options.first }}> % else %} <{{ product.options.first }}>{{ variant.option1 }}</{{ product.options.first }}> <{{ product.options[1] }}>{{ variant.option2 }}</{{ product.options[1] }}> {% endif %}`

Where the output is:

`<color>White</color>
 <size>S</size>`

If you have a simpler solution by all means :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I follow you 100%, but from your example you should be doing this instead:

```
{% for product_option in product.options_with_values %}
    {%- for value in product_option.values -%}
        <{{ product_option.name }}>{{value}}</{{ product_option.name }}>
    {%- endfor -%}
{% endfor %}
```

Where that output will be:

`<color>Blue</color><color>Red</color><color>Green</color>...<size>M</size><size>S</size>...`

Comment: Very very close! However, I only need to display the option and value associated with that specific variant. Here is how achieved it:                                                              
`{% if product.options.size == 1 %}
<{{ product.options.first }}>{{ variant.option1 }}</{{ product.options.first }}>
% else %}
<{{ product.options.first }}>{{ variant.option1 }}</{{ product.options.first }}>
<{{ product.options[1] }}>{{ variant.option2 }}</{{ product.options[1] }}>
{% endif %}`  If you have a much simpler approach` .  If you have a simpler solution by all means :)